# How to add an animated gif as a featured image to woocommerce product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gif, animated-gif

I'm trying to add an animated gif to woocomerce product as a featured image, but it just doesn't load. Is there a plugin or a code tweak that can help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: use `custom fields` instead of featured images

Comment: Hello Pravin. Can you please elaborate? Actually I'm not a core developer so a bit difficult for me to understand.

Comment: It's Ok. Actually `Advanced custom field` is a plugin but you need to work on `woocommerce` core file adding in your theme. Any idea about that?

Comment: I've tried it now, it works without problem. The gif loads as expected..